# How to run JavaScript prior to System.Web.UI.Timer OnTick?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-3.5, timer, confirmation

I need a client-side script to confirm that the Timer's OnTick event can proceed.

How do I invoke *CanContinue()* before the Timer1 postback occurs? 
 
How do I cancel the postback if user selects Cancel?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Timer1_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Last Postback: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Timer Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CanContinue() {
            return confirm('The page is requesting new data.  Ok or Cancel?');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_OnTick" Interval="300000" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

NOTE: Some readers might take issue with showing a modal confirmation every x minutes.  I would agree that this is poor for usability, but I'm not in a position to change the design.

---

UPDATE: I decided not to use a Timer after all.  See [this post](http://robertclaypool.info/2009/01/21/javascript-and-timer-ontick/) for details on an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use a Timer after all. See [this post](http://robertclaypool.info/2009/01/21/javascript-and-timer-ontick/) for details on an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to tie in to the method generated by the timer to invoke the server action.  However you can gain a reference to the javascript component and start/stop or change the interval.  With this in mind, you can do some nasty hacking to get the functionality you want.

For instance:

1. Gain a reference to your timer.  (something like: `$find(‘<%= Timer1.ClientID %>’);`)
2. Stop the timer.
3. Create a new timer with the same interval.
4. Execute your timer and cause the condition.
5. Depending on the return value of your condition.. you can set the server generated timer interval to ~0 and start/stop.

This is not an elegant solution, but I can't say i've ever worked with built in asp.net timers so I can't offer too much insight.